# Applying function to multiple columns in View

Tags: mysql, sql, function, view

I have a MYSQL View in which I have the following:

```
SELECT
    claim_month_id,
    claim.claim_id,
    month.month_id,
    paid_to_date - CASE WHEN (end_date > reported_to_insurer_date) 
    THEN LAG( paid_to_date, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id ) 
    ELSE 0 END AS paid_change,
    days_paid - CASE WHEN (end_date > reported_to_insurer_date) 
    THEN LAG( days_paid, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id ) 
    ELSE 0 END AS days_paid_change,
    wks_paid - CASE WHEN (end_date > reported_to_insurer_date) 
    THEN LAG( wks_paid, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id ) 
    ELSE 0 END AS wks_paid_change...
```

These last couple of lines are repeated over a series of columns; there are multiple numeric columns each with the same function applied. Is there some way of streamlining the SQL such that it is a lot easier to read? It's even more useful since I've decided I want to change some details regarding the algorithm which now has to be done across every field rather than just changing the source.

My vision is something like

```
SELECT
    claim_month_id,
    claim.claim_id,
    month.month_id,
    VIEWDIFF(paid_to_date) AS paid_to_date_change,
    VIEWDIFF(days_paid) AS days_paid_change,
    VIEWDIFF(wks_paid) AS wks_paid_change
```

with some way of defining a VIEWDIFF function.

My background is functional programming so I'm trying to make my way back to the mothership. I know it's a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the right search terms to find an answer here.

Comment: I'm going to say "No", and the reason is that you won't be able to invoke the relevant lag() function or the over clause inside a scalar function (because the scalar function knows nothing about the query that calls it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MySQL 8x

It is possible to form a "derived table" and through that get the ability to refer to calculated columns via their alias: e.g.

```
select 
    *
  , paid_to_date - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_paid_to_date
        ELSE 0
    END AS paid_change
  , days_paid - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_days_paid
        ELSE 0
    END AS days_paid_change
  , wks_paid - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_wks_paid
        ELSE 0
    END AS wks_paid_change
FROM (
    SELECT
          *
        , LAG(paid_to_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id) AS lag_paid_to_date
        , LAG(days_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id)    AS lag_days_paid
        , LAG(wks_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id)     AS lag_wks_paid
    FROM x
    ) d
```

OR, you can use a `common table expression` (cte) instead, which makes it appear more "serial" like in logic terms e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
          *
        , LAG(paid_to_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id) AS lag_paid_to_date
        , LAG(days_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id)    AS lag_days_paid
        , LAG(wks_paid, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY claim_id ORDER BY month_id)     AS lag_wks_paid
    FROM x
)

SELECT 
    *
  , paid_to_date - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_paid_to_date
        ELSE 0
    END AS paid_change
  , days_paid - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_days_paid
        ELSE 0
    END AS days_paid_change
  , wks_paid - CASE
        WHEN end_date > reported_to_insurer_date THEN lag_wks_paid
        ELSE 0
    END AS wks_paid_change
FROM cte
```

Personally I prefer to use cte's for specific purposes such as recursion, but it is increasingly used in lieu of simple derived tables.